How to integrate with specific identity in Nspire CX II CAS.
If I calculate by hand the following integral using identities:
$\int\cos^3(x)\sin^2(x)dx
= -\frac{\sin(x)^5}{5} + \frac{\sin(x)^3}{3}$
But the calculator gives me the following answer : $-\frac{1}{15}\sin(x)(3\cos^4(x)−\cos^2(x)−2)​$.
I know is equivalent but I want to know if there is a way to get the simplified answer from this calculator.

What identities do you know of/ have you tried? That gives us a better idea of how to help

On a new line in the calculator, use the substitution $\cos{x} = \sqrt{1 - t^2}$ on the integral (where $t = \sin{x}$), and see if the polynomial matches with your answer.
